# Product of non-negative measurable and integrable functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Here is the problem that I have

> Let $f \in \Sigma^+$ and $h \in \Sigma$ and the measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ are such that $\nu(E)=\mu(\mathbb{1}_E f)$ for any $E \in \Sigma$. Then $h \in \mathcal{L}^1(S,\Sigma, \nu)$ iff $hf \in \mathcal{L}^1(S,\Sigma,\mu)$, in which case one has $\nu(h) = \mu(hf)$.

A few clarifications that I think are very specific to the notation my professor uses: $\nu(h)$ means the integral of $h$ w.r.t. a measure $\nu$. When referring to a function, $\Sigma^+$ is the set of measurable non-negative functions, $\Sigma$ is the set of measurable functions. When referring to a set, the later is simply a sigma-algebra. $\mathbb{1}_E$ is the characteristic (identificator) function w.r.t. set $E$

The way I see it, I have to prove that the product $hf$ is integrable w.r.t. measure $\mu()$ if and only if $\nu(h)=\mu(hf)$ .

I'm trying to go through the definition of integrable but i don't get it. I denote the integral of $h$ w.r.t. measure $\nu()$ and by definition I know that a function is integrable if for

$$h = h^+ - h^-$$

where $h^+=max(0,h)$, $h^-=max(0,-h)$

I have that $$\nu(h) = \nu(h^+) - \nu(h^-)$$ and $\nu(h^-)<\infty$, $\nu(h^+)\infty$ where by $\nu(h)$ I denote the integral w.r.t. measure $\nu()$, etc.

I have difficulty however seeing how one transitions from one measure to another.

Comment: Do I have to use proof by standard machine?

Comment: Are you sure about the statement of the problem? Take $f(x)=x$ and $h(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ on $[1,\infty]$, then $f$ is non-negative and measurable, $h$ is integrable, but $g(x)=f(x)\cdot h(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not.

Comment: I think you are right. I'm not reading it probably. I will correct now

Comment: You say you've corrected this, but the current version makes no sense, for several  reasons. State the problem **exactly** as it appears in the book (or  wherever). With the same words, in the same order. Don't leave anything out,  and don't rephrase  anything.

Comment: OK, I have edited and posted the exact problem, as I have in my Measure Theory script. Sorry for any confustion, I'm still struggling with the concepts and the correct way of writing down

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this is a correct statement of the problem. Because (i) the first assertion is  obviously false and (ii) the second part, "in which case...", makes no sense! What is $\mu$?

Comment: Sorry, one typo. $hf$ is integrable w.r.t. measure $\mu$ (I had written wrongly $\nu$ again). At the same time $\mu(hf)$ means the integral of the product of functions $hf$ w.r.t. measure $\mu$

Comment: **What is $\mu$???**

Comment: When referring to $\mathcal{L}^1(S,\Sigma,\mu)$, $\mu$ is some measure. When referring to $\mu(hf)$, it means the Lebesgue integral of function $hf$ w.r.t. that measure

Comment: If you're honestly not given anything about $\mu$ other than that it's some measure then the problem  is _obviously_ wrong -  if there's no relation between $|nu$ and $\mu$ then one function being integrable wrt $\nu$ obviously can't say anything about another function beiing integrable wrt $\mu$.

Comment: you're right. There was a previous condition that related $\mu$ and $\nu$. I have now edited the problem to add it. Sorry for that. The problem was just stated in a confusing way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're given a measure space $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ and a non-negative measurable function $f\colon S \to [0,\infty]$.

Consider $\nu$ such that $\displaystyle\nu(E)=\int_E f\, d\mu \quad\forall E\in\Sigma$. It's a measure on $(S,\Sigma)$ and
$$
\int_E h\,d\nu = \int_E hf\,d\mu
$$
for every measurable function $h$.

This also tells you that $h\in\mathcal{L}^1(S,\Sigma,\nu)$ iff $hf\in\mathcal{L}^1(S,\Sigma,\mu)$.

To prove the equivalence of the integrals use the "standard machine" (prove it for simple functions, then non-negative ones via Monotone Convergence Theorem, lastly for real valued functions decomposing them into positive and negative part).
Pay attention to put the correct sign when decomposing $h$:
$$
h=h^+\color{red}{-}h^-.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $h(x)=1$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for $0<x\le 1$, $f(0)=0$. Both are measurable, $f$ is nonnegative, $h$ is integrable on $[0,1]$. But the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^1 (fg) \, dx$ diverges.

Comment: $f=0$ gives obvious counter-examples.

Comment: ... for the converse implication.

Comment: yes, I have corrected the problem